# How to listen to changes in a document of some collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, real-time-updates

I am using socket.io for Real-time communication between server and client so , i wanted to listen to changes in the specific document to update the online list to the client
Here is my Schema for the collection:

```
var registerCompanySchema = new Schema({
              sn : { type: Number, unique:true }
              , companyName: String
              , employees:[String],
               companyId:{type:Number,unique:true},
               onlineEmployees:[String]  //uname
          });
```

I am using a array 'onlineEmployees' to store the username of employees who are currently online
I am new to mongoDB....Please provide some details with your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watching the oplog is probably your best bet, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014839/get-notification-for-changed-documents-in-mongodb).

- [Get notification for changed documents in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014839/get-notification-for-changed-documents-in-mongodb)
- [Replication Internals](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/10/12/replication-internals/) - includes a bunch of detail on the oplog

If you're using `mongoskin` you can try a variant on [this example from their wiki](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/wiki/Using-tailable-cursors):

```
skin = require "mongoskin"
db = skin.db "localhost:27017/local"

#Cursor on oplog (a capped collection) which maintains a history for replication
#oplog can be used only when replication is enabled
# Use oplog.rs instead of oplog.$main if you are using replica set

oplog = db.collection "oplog.$main"
cursor = oplog.find({'ns': "icanvc.projects"},{tailable: yes, awaitData: yes})

#Using cursor.nextObject will be slow
cursor.each (err, log)->
    console.error err if err
    console.log log if not err
```

Comment: Thanks for your help....I am using mongolab for mongodb hosting so getting an op-log can be done when db is in localhost, but what about in my case ..?

Comment: You need admin privileges, which we do offer on some plans. You can write us at support@mongolab.com to discuss options.