# Alerts from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I am planning to create an independent notification system using MongoDB for persistence. Is there any way to get notifications from MongoDB if a particular collection changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. There are no triggers or such.

What you could do is a (very) poor man's solution of a message queue with MongoDB.

1. Create a capped collection, which can be used as a FIFO buffer for messages.
2. Connect it via a [tailable cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/)
3. Skip all existing entries in the capped collection and wait for new ones.

Comment: Hey Markus, am planning to build some tool to get sync with monogdb.Am not reinventing wheel.

Comment: Your first sentence states differently. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As of MongoDb 3.6 you can subscribe to a change stream. More details here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47184757/5103354