# How to get notified when a new field is added to mongodb collections?

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I have a graphQl schema defined which needs to be changed runtime whenever there is a new field added in a mongodb collection. For example, a collection has just two fields before

```
    person { 
             "age" : "54"
             "name" : "Tony"
           }
```

And later a new field, "height" is added.

```
        person { 
             "age" : "54"
             "name" : "Tony"
             "height" : "167"

           }
```

I need to change my graphql schema and add height to that. So how do I get alerted or notifications from Mongodb ?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not natively implement event messaging. You cannot, natively, get informed of a DB, collections or document updates.

However, MongoDB integrates an ['operation log'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) feature, which allows you to get access to a journal log of each write operation on collections.

The journal logs are used for MongoDB replicas, aka cluster synchronization features. In order to activate `oplogs` you need to have at least two MongoDB instances, a master and [a replicate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/).

Operations logs are built upon the [`capped collection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) feature, which allows a collection to be built over an append-only mechanism, which ensures fast writes and tailing cursors. Authors say:

> The oplog exists internally as a capped collection, so you cannot
>   modify its size in the course of normal operations.
>
> *[MongoDB - Change the Size of the Oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/)*

And:

> Capped collections are fixed-size collections that support
>   high-throughput operations that insert and retrieve documents based on
>   insertion order. Capped collections work in a way similar to circular
>   buffers: once a collection fills its allocated space, it makes room
>   for new documents by overwriting the oldest documents in the
>   collection.
>
> *[MongoDB - Capped Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/)*

The schema of the documents within an operation log journal looks like:

```
"ts" : Timestamp(1395663575, 1),
"h" : NumberLong("-5872498803080442915"),
"v" : 2,
"op" : "i",
"ns" : "wiktory.items",
"o" : {
  "_id" : ObjectId("533022d70d7e2c31d4490d22"),
  "author" : "JRR Hartley",
  "title" : "Flyfishing"
  }
}
```

Eg: `"op" : "i"` means operation is an insertion and `"o"` is the object inserted.

The same way, you can be informed of `update` operations:

```
"op" : "u",
"ns" : "wiktory.items",
"o2" : {
  "_id" : ObjectId("533022d70d7e2c31d4490d22")
},
"o" : {
  "$set" : {
    "outofprint" : true
  }
}
```

Note that the operation logs (you access them as collections) are limited either in disk size or entry numbers (FIFO). This means that, eventually, whwnever your oplog consumers are slower than oplog writers, you will get missed operation log entries, resulting in corrupted consumption results.

This is the reason why MongoDB is terrible for guaranteeing document tracking on highly sollicited clusters, and the reason why solutions for messaging such as [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) come as supplements for event tracking (eg: event `document update`)

To answer your question: in a reasonably solicited environment, you might want to take a look at the Javascript [Meteor project](https://www.meteor.com/), which allows you to trigger events based on changes from queries results, and relies on MongoDB oplog features.

*Credits: oplogs examples from [The MongoDB Oplog](https://www.compose.com/articles/the-mongodb-oplog-and-node-js/)*

Answer (score 1):

As of MongoDb 3.6 you can subscribe to a change stream. You could subscribe to an "update" event operation. More details here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47184757/5103354